# Is it possible to do something like this in LESS?

Tags: css, less

How to create something like this in LESS???

```
.class-1,
.class-2,
.class-3,
.
.
.
.class-n {
    float: left;
    /* More... */
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this? --there is probably a better way.

Comment: Yes, more context is required to give you anything remotely approaching a useful answer.

Comment: This is possible in case of SASS. I just want to know is it possible with LESS??? Nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have the answer (which is YES): http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/

Comment: Well, really like `.class-1 {float:left}, .class-2 {float:left;}`, etc ... but it's the same thing, no?

Comment: No.That is not the answer. It ll create something like this .class-1 { }, .class-2 { }. But i want .class-1, .class-2.... .class-n { }

Comment: I got the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153688/multiple-selectors-in-loop-in-less?rq=1

Comment: We should use extend function in LESS.

Comment: @andi: Please add the sample code from that link to your answer mate. Link only answers are typically frowned upon and may even result in removal of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what `n` you need... There's crazy trick to get a recursive selector counter besides "recursive mixin loop": https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6651319
Adopting that dodge to your code gives something like that:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 { &, &0, && {
    class-& {
        float: left;
        /* More... */
    }
}}
```

Comment: Wow, that is really clever use of the parent selector. Couldn't resist upvoting (though I prefer loops).